# Advice on selecting a replacement transistor for a high voltage transformer

Tags: transistors

We can replace a resistor or capacitor with somewhat similar characteristics if same not available. Similarly I want to know if we can replace a transistor with some other and is there any golden rule for this?
As in my case I want to replace BD679 with BD540 or BD711 as both are available to me.

I'm using it with a 555 timer.

BD711 datasheet

```
Material of transistor: Si
Polarity: NPN
Maximum collector power dissipation (Pc), W: 75
Maximum collector-base voltage |Ucb|, V: 100
Maximum collector-emitter voltage |Uce|, V: 100
Maximum emitter-base voltage |Ueb|, V: 5
Maximum collector current |Ic max|, A: 12
Maksimalna temperatura (Tj), °C: 150
Transition frequency (ft), MHz: 3
Collector capacitance (Cc), pF:
Forward current transfer ratio (hFE), min: 15
Noise Figure, dB: -
Package of BD711 transistor: TO220
```

BD679 datasheet

```
Type Designator: BD679
Material of transistor: Si
Polarity: NPN
Maximum collector power dissipation (Pc), W: 40
Maximum collector-base voltage |Ucb|, V: 80
Maximum collector-emitter voltage |Uce|, V: 80
Maximum emitter-base voltage |Ueb|, V: 5
Maximum collector current |Ic max|, A: 4
Maksimalna temperatura (Tj), °C: 150
Transition frequency (ft), MHz: 1
Collector capacitance (Cc), pF:
Forward current transfer ratio (hFE), min: 750
Noise Figure, dB: -
Package of BD679 transistor: TO126
```

[image: Here is the schematic from http://www.555-timer-circuits.com/stun-gun.html]

Comment: You need to compare the specifications for each transistor based on their datasheets.  If you want help from this site, you also need to tell us what the application is so that the most relevant specifications can be identified.

Comment: Check / compare their data sheets.

Comment: That is what I'm asking what features are important to be compared for resistor it is it's value and power rating

Comment: When the board is fixed, you first have to find a transistor with the same package and the same pin arrangement - dont forget the tab connection- (and of course, it has to be the same sort - NPN/PNP, Darlingon-NPN/PNP, NFET, PFET, NMOS, PMOS, N-IGBT, P-IGBT etc.) Next, you have to check the power dissipation, the collector-emitter voltage and the collector current. These have to match your application, not necessarily the original transistor's maximum ratings.

Comment: A transistor has many specifications, and just *which ones* are of importance in a particular application drives the replacement search. There *is no one size fits all* for this activity.

Comment: You need to post a schematic so that we can identify which parameters are important.

Comment: A BD679 is a [Darlington transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darlington_transistor), which is effectively two transistors in one package to get a higher gain (see hFE = 750). A BD711 is not (hFE = 15), so you may need another transistor to drive it, but without a circuit diagram we can't help there. A BD540 is a PNP transistor, so that is completely not suitable.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the BD679 is from a series of complementary darlingtons; the BD680 is the PNP complement in this case. If your circuit is using the complementary set, you need to look for another complementary pair. On semiconductor states that the  BD679 is equivalent to the MJE802. http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=BD679

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to replace a rubber hose in some equipment and could not find the exact replacement what would you do?

- Would you only look for one that has the same fittings?
- Would you look for one with the same fittings and same internal pipe diameter?
- Would you do some dimensional checking then decide whether product A or B was best, based on what pressure and flow rate and fluid type was being transported?

The latter one is what you should do because not understanding the application for your hose could mean it burts (because of over-pressure) or burts because of material incompatibilities (i.e. the fluid degrades the rubber used).

It's the same with transistors.

Comment: That means a lot work I wanted to know if there is any rule that goes by the series with consecutive series being replaceable.BTW thanks for the advice and hope the hose I try fits the equipment ;-)

Comment: Anecdote - I've found some circuits that won't accept a transistor from supplier B but work with supplier A (even though the part numbers are the same). It's mainly down to the target application/design.